# Issues with large CSV import into MySQL57 - incorrect integer values within some columns

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble importing a 800 MB CSV file into MySQL 5.7.

Basically, I am getting warning(s) for 3 columns, in specific rows as below:

> 5290818 row(s) affected, 6 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value:
>   '' for column 'hotel_id' at row 308 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''
>   for column 'currency_id' at row 336 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''
>   for column 'hotel_id' at row 339 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for
>   column 'available_cnt' at row 7399 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''
>   for column 'available_cnt' at row 7508 1366 Incorrect integer value:
>   '' for column 'available_cnt' at row 7700 Records: 5290818  Deleted: 0
>   Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6

I understand this requires substituting user variables for the problematic columns, and performing some checks.

However, I don't understand the syntax, could someone please explain it to me?

Thank you!

Here's what I used to import the CSV file into MYSQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Li/Downloads/offer.csv' 
INTO TABLE offer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

And here's the code for the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `primary_data`.`oFfer` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_system_code` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `available_cnt` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellings_price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `checkin_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `checkout_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `valid_offer_flag` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `offer_valid_from` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `offer_valid_to` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `breakfast_included_flag` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `insert_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Comment: Duplicate the Table as import_data. Change the INT fields to varchar. Import, then select, run checks and insert to primary_data. I import very large csv files (65,000 rows+) this way especially when I cannot control the format of its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's only a small number of items, this task can be tackled manually. First thing to note is that mysql does not offer any guarantees about a 'default sort order'. However since this is a fresh table, we can be confident that the rows are returned in the same order they were inserted in. So the following query will show you what's at 308:

```
SELECT * FROM offer LIMIT 307, 1
```

Note that offset has to be 1 less than the actual row number. Now you can update it with the proper value (using the id that was revealed to you by the above query)

```
UPDATE offer set hotel_id = something where id = someid
```

Repeat this 5 times and you are done.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Since you are new user here, permit me to point out that it's customary to accept an answer if it is correct. This way someone who lands on this page in the future knows that the solution will work for them. Beside we both get brownie points :)

Comment: Yes noted, will do :)